# iOS Swift - How to use deeplink callback?

Tags: ios, swift

My app scenario is the following:

1. Source app opens Target app with some params e.g. `target-scheme://action?someParams...`
2. Target app picks up, process data and shows alert. User taps OK.
3. Target app opens back Source app with another params e.g. `source-scheme://action?someParams...`

The thing is, target app shouldn't know about Source app(s), meaning, it shouldn't add scheme to LSApplicationQueriesSchemes for each new Source app.

Is there way to use callback without openURL function and avoid LSApplicationQueriesSchemes editing, which is required when using openURL?

Comment: You can adopt universal links in the Source App, they look like regular https:// links and don't require the calling app to modify LSApplicationQueriesSchemes.

Comment: But then I need to setup a server, and call that server, right?

Comment: You need to set up a server to host the .well-known/apple-app-site-association file, but it doesn't need to process the data in any way

Comment: Yeah, you just need a domain and any web server to serve the apple-app-site-association file. This file links your domain with your App ID, this is the way to prove that you're the rightful owner of the app and the domain and to prevent other apps from hijacking your universal links.